# Getting error: expected unqualified-id before 'default'

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I am trying to write a basic program to show the use of default constructors. This is my code below;

```
class Fraction
{
private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;

public:
    Fraction() // default constructor
    {
         m_numerator = 0;
         m_denominator = 1;
    }

    int getNumerator() { return m_numerator; }
    int getDenominator() { return m_denominator; }
    double getValue() { return static_cast<double>(m_numerator) / m_denominator; }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Fraction default; // Since no arguments, calls Fraction() default constructor
    std::cout << default.getNumerator() << "/" << default.getDenominator() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error message in the main program saying, 'expected unqualified-id before 'default' I think I am missing something simple, but I can't spot it!

Comment: The syntax highlighter gives it away :-)

Comment: default is a key word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`default` is a keyword in C++; you must not use it as an identifier. Pick a different name.

Comment: Suggestions: `Fraction defau1t, defauIt, defualt, default_, defAult;`

Comment: Good man Kerrek, thanks very much! Frank

Comment: Serious suggestions: `defaultFraction`, `emptyFraction`, `defaultConstructed`, `zero`, `zeroOverOne`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't name your variables `default`. Re-name your variable to something else.